# Pure Java Less implementation

Tags: java, less

I am looking for pure-java Less engine. This means that I don't want to introduce any unnecessary dependencies on Rhino, JRuby and stuff like that.
Is there even such an implementation?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? http://www.asual.com/lesscss/

Comment: actual.com/lesscss is one of those libraries which use Rhino and JS interpretation to do the job.

Comment: here is repo https://github.com/jryans/jless
It's a port of less ruby

Comment: Look at https://github.com/i-net-software/jlessc It is a pure Java implementation.